# How to create a snapshot in XCode7

Tags: xcode7

The "snapshot" function seems to have disappeared in xcode7-beta.

Under projects you can still see snapshots to restore.

Under file there is no create snapshot
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Windows > Projects and the snap shots are available there.

Comment: How do you add one, please supply a screen shot

Comment: In Xcode 6.4, the Preferences > Behaviors menu had an option you could turn on: "Create a Snapshot" at many steps. Also, there are File menu entries to create and restore a snapshot. Those are all removed in 7.2. Apple forums have said in the past that you need to do scm commits before doing big edits such as refactoring.

Comment: Apple forums have said in the past that you need to do scm commits before doing big edits such as refactoring. Since the behaviors have the script entry, you can put a script in of your own, e.g. gnutar -czf file.gz <project dir>.